# Why does BigQuery's "WITH" clause return an error when it references a external table (federated source)?

Tags: google-bigquery

This appears to be a bug, and I'm happy to post it in the official BigQuery tracker if it is, but I thought I'd ask on SO first  - just case we're doing something wrong/stupid.

OK, so we have a an external table (CSV file in GCS). It works perfectly fine when querying it in BigQuery. However, when it's used from within a `WITH` clause, BigQuery chokes with the following error:

> *"The job encountered an internal error during execution and was unable
>   to complete successfully."*

Checking the job details shows no more details.

Here's a simple example:

```
WITH
  foo AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    TMP.fed_source_gcs), <-- this is a file in GCS
  bar AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `bigquery-samples.reddit.words`
  LIMIT
    100)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  bar <-- not referencing foo but query fails
```

This fails. Sample job id: **bquijob_6f4422d6_15b9e1a61cf**[image]

Oddly enough, if I query the temp table (`foo`) directly, then it works perfectly fine e.g.:

```
WITH
  foo AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    TMP.fed_source_gcs),
  bar AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `bigquery-samples.reddit.words`
  LIMIT
    100)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  foo <-- now referencing foo and query succeeds
```

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: "An internal error occured" is always a bug.

Comment: Thanks @MoshaPasumansky. So I should report it on the official tracker than right?

Comment: Yes, with tracker it is easier to keep track of :)

Comment: No problem @MoshaPasumansky. I'll file it.

Comment: Could you please post the project id, so that we can have a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, this is a bug in BigQuery, and there is an official issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37616835).